# Is that a shorter way assigning properties with LINQ Query Syntax?

Tags: linq, linq-query-syntax

Say I have a list of an object with 30 properties (eg: `Items`)

If I am using LINQ Query-Syntax to `Join` another object (eg: `Store`), it seems inevitable that i have to re-assign every property from the `Item`, right?

For example:

```
    var temp = from a in items
               join b in stores on a.storeKey = b.storeKey into b2
               from c in b2.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new ItemViewModel()
               {
                  p1 = a.p1,
                  p2 = a.p2,
                  ....
                  p30 = a.p2, //re-assign 30 times (T.T)

                  storeInfo1 = c.storeInfo1 //all i want is 1 or 2 additional info from store
               }
```

Comment: Provide a copy constructor or factory method in `ItemViewModel` that takes an `Items` instance as parameter.

Comment: lol i think i saw the answer from you disappearing while i am digesting your words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a library such as [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/). For property names that are the same between `a` and `ItemViewModel` it can do the mapping for you using reflection, for properties with different names you can define a manual mapping, and for properties coming from the other objects (b and c) you can use a helper.

Something like this:

```
var temp = from a in items
           join b in stores on a.storeKey = b.storeKey into b2
           from c in b2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select CreateModelFrom(a, b, c);

public ItemViewModel CreateModelFrom(ObjA a, ObjB b, ObjC c)
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<ObjA, ItemViewModel>();
    model.xxx = b.xxx;
    model.storeInfo1 = c.storeInfo1;
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the requirement I think you should change your class structure. Their are two ways

1. ItemViewModel should be derived from same class as of items or
2. it should a property inside in it

I am writing the second way

```
class Item
{
     string p1;
     ......
}

class ItemViewModel
{
     string p1;
     ......
     string storeInfo1;
     Item item;

     ItemViewModel(Item item, string storeInfo)
     {
        this.item= item;
        this.storeInfo1 = storeInfo;
     }
}

var temp = from a in items
           join b in stores on a.storeKey = b.storeKey into b2
           from c in b2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new ItemViewModel(a, c.storeInfo1);
```

Comment: This means that property access will need to be done using `model.item.p1`. Also it means that the ViewModel now has a dependency on the data class, which is often unwanted and a reason to use ViewModels in the first place.